# What is the name for a fraction whose expansion extends forever?

Tags: fractions, irrational-numbers

Irrespective of whether it is a rational number like $\frac{1}{3}$, an irrational number, like $2^{1/2}$ or a transcendental number, like $\pi$, is there a word for all decimal fractions which continue without end?

Comment: This is highly dependent on your choice of base so I'm not 100% sure we have a name beyond "non-terminating decimal expansion [in base b]". That said, any rational will either have a terminating or repeating decimal expansion in any integer base, and any irrational will have an infinite, non-repeating decimal expansion in any integer base.

Comment: Yes, I was awkwardly aware of that when I asked. Perhaps there is a word for numbers with fractional parts which extend forever in whichever base the representation is being considered?

Comment: Yes, that was the first word which came to me. The trouble was, I was thinking of it in the context of binary truncation in digital number systems. In this case, when the base is given, it includes some rational numbers, like (1/10)_2.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Great summary, an even better word would be "periodic" instead of "repeating".

Comment: @CameronWilliams Is "decimal" a correct term for the expansion in base $b$?

Comment: @user every base is base 10! Flippancy aside, you're right though, that is not quite the right terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every real number *can* be written as a nonterminating decimal expansion using trickery like $.999999... = 1$, so the question should really be, which numbers are *forced* to be written as a nonterminating expansion.

First consider a slightly easier question, which numbers are forced to be written as a nonrepeating expansion? The answer to this question is independent of the base (so long as it is integral >= 2) chosen for the expansion, and it is the irrational numbers. The proof of this goes by long division and noting that division by an integer gives only finitely many possible choices for remainder, so repetition will eventually occur. Thus, in any base any irrational number must be represented in a nonterminating expansion.

Then the question remains, of the rational numbers, which amongst them can be written in a nonterminating expansion. E.g. $1/10 = .1$ but $1/3=.33333333...$ must repeat base 10.
This question's answer obviously does depend on the base, so lets fix a base $b$.
To say that $x$ has a terminating expansion in base $b$ means that
$x = \sum_{i=-k}^na_i b^{-i}$ for a finite $n,k$ and some $a_{-k}, \ldots, a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \{0,1,\ldots, b-1\}$. This is possible iff multiplying by a large power of $b$ gives an integer, so we conclude that $x$ has a finite representation in base $b$ if and only if it is a rational number which can be written as $a/b^n$ for $a, n $ integers with $n \geq 0$.

Such numbers are called $b$-adic numbers, most commonly considered only for primes $p$, and referred to as $p$-adic numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational

Thus the answer to your question is that $x$ must have a nonterminating expansion in base $b$ iff it $x$ is not $b$-adic (this includes all irrationals).

Comment: Very interesting, and helpful, thank you. Is there also a word for such $b$-adic numbers in base 10?

Comment: "Decimal fractions" or just "decimals". The answer was there all along ;) . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#Decimal_fractions

Comment: I believe this is as complete an answer to this question as can be. Thank you.